# Translation of "thank goodness" or "whew!"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, interjecciones

In English, if a bad situation seems imminent but is finally avoided, we might reply with an interjection like "Thank goodness!" or "Whew!". I know "Thank goodness!" has several possible translations at the beginning of a sentence, but I'm thinking of it being used as a standalone interjection. What is typically said in Spanish in situations like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A usual translation for the interjection "Whew!" is

> ¡Fiu!

In these situations it is common to say:

> ¡Qué alivio!

It is also common to say

> Me salvé por un pelo.

In Uruguay we say also "En el anca de un piojo" but I don't know if this is common elsewhere.

to express how close to the bad situation we had come.

"Thank goodness" might also be "Gracias a Dios", but this may have a religious component.

A common verb is "zafar". For example,

> El profesor estaba interrogando alumnos al azar, pero yo zafé por estar en una esquinita, medio oculto.

Comment: Nice answer! "En el anca de un piojo" is not known in Colombia and Ecuador. Other countries I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Bruno's answer you can say these aswell:

> ¡Gracias al cielo!
>
> ¡Menos mal!
>
> ¡Uf!

and for some humor we say sometimes this in Colombia:

> Me salvé por un pelo de rana calva.

The translation would be **I saved myself by the hair of a bald frog**. Since frogs have no hair, a bald frog would have even less hair. So he saved himself by so little!